# Setting animation from variable start

Tags: unity, animation

So I have a fun little animation where this monkey swings his feet however ! I am not sure where he will be in this animation when the player hands him this coconut which should trigger another animation that returns him to a stationary position.

In Unity how can I take the characters current position and use it as the start position for the animation ?

Comment: Are you talking about sprites or 3d models? Because with 3d models, if the monkey and the player are humanoids, then you could perhaps solve this problem with inverse kinematics.

Comment: They are 3D models :), I haven't heard of inverse kinematics how does that work with the animator ?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure where he will be in this animation when the player hands him this coconut which should trigger another animation that returns him to a stationary position.

That doesn't matter if you manage the animations using the Animator component. The Animator component already supports [transitions with animation blending](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Transition.html). Just create a transition from one animation state to another.

[image: Animator and Inspector panels]

Comment: Awesome was the easiest solution for me.